# Xcode 12 does not read data from outlets, does not color code and autofill

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, xcode-storyboard

In every project I do, I tend to have the same problem with my Xcode
I am new to swift programming learning it for about a week, but because of this problem, I can't go on with my lessons. I create a new project.
[So I begin like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkTW6.png)  And basically I don't know another way to do it. [Then I configure it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIEvM.png) which is I guess the only option. Then I add a label from the library, open the assistant, and control drag [to connect it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnTbz.png) after the connection is made I cannot get to the properties of the UI element. In the identity inspector `ViewController` class is connected as well [As it is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrqv8.jpg). Would you tell me what am I doing wrong? Because I am stuck. I am new to this and I know the problem must be small but I can't proceed.

Comment: Your Xcode autocomplete might simply be broken and might require a restart. Are you able to confirm that your IBOutlet is connected, maybe assign a string to labelTextTest such as labelTextTest.text = "Hello"

Comment: When the code is written it works perfectly fine.  if I assign some data to element it works. But I need to write everything by myself, with no proposals from Xcode, and it is hard and pointless.

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects, - Clean build folder
- Delete derived data
- Close/reopen Xcode
- Restart mac

Comment: Make sure "Suggest completions while typing" is also checked in Xcode Preferences in Text Editing.

Comment: Did all that as well, those are new Mac, and every new project in Xcode  I try to create, I am in despair